# Stop UIPickerView from automatically Hide when setting UIButton Title Text

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uibutton, uipickerview

My UIPickerView Working perfect. Apparently I got confused with its behaviour - if I keep below code my picker remain visible (which is exactly what I want)

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  NSLog(@"=====");
}
```

Now If I just one line Picker automatically get hidden and my button title label also get set with appropriate value.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  [MyButtonObj setTitle:myarray[row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I am not getting why setting button title makes `uipickerview` hidden automatically.

On button click I am displaying pickerview using View animation.

```
if (!isPickerDisplay) 
{ 
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{ 
    CGRect temp = _ownPickerView.frame; 
    temp.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - _ownPickerView.frame.size.height; 
    _ownPickerView.frame = temp; 
  } 
  completion:^(BOOL finished) 
  { 
    NSLog(@"picker displayed"); 
    isPickerDisplay = YES; 
  }]; 
}
```

Comment: How is the picker view presented?

Comment: On button click I am displaying pickerview using View animation.

if (!isPickerDisplay) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            CGRect temp = _ownPickerView.frame;
            temp.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - _ownPickerView.frame.size.height;
            _ownPickerView.frame = temp;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            NSLog(@"picker displayed");
            isPickerDisplay = YES;
        }];
    }

Comment: Put code in your question, not in comments.